# How to center image through height in carousel Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Hello I'm very new to this great community and very unexpert coder
I have a problem, I would like that the images in the carousel I have will have be in the centered by height.
 The image is bigger the the carousel, I would like to just center them just to show the best part of the foto not just the upper part.
My carousel: [example1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9vCJ.jpg)
How I would like to see it (opaque part is the rest of the image): [example2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0oBPS.jpg)
I hope I explained myself.
This is some code
HTML

```
    <!--Carousel Wrapper-->
<div id="carousel-home" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel">
    <!--Indicators-->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carousel-home" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-home" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-home" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <!--Slides-->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
            <div class="view">
                <img class="d-block w-100 mx-auto" src="imgs/slider/1.png" alt="First slide">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h3>Light mask</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="d-block w-100 mx-auto" src="imgs/slider/2.png" alt="Second slide">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h3>Strong mask</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="d-block w-100 mx-auto" src="imgs/slider/3.png" alt="Third slide">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h3>Slight mask</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--Controls-->
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carousel-home" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carousel-home" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.carousel-inner 
{ 
width:100%; 
max-height:350px; 
}
.carousel-caption 
{
    text-align: center;
    bottom: 70%;
}
```

Comment: `.carousel-item img { object-fit: cover }` done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you want to crop the image based on the image height.

So `object-fit` probably is not something you want. This is the css trick based on your question.

you want to add `img-crop` to your `<img>`, and adjust the percentage.
But this solution is depending on the original height of the image so you might be aware of that.

```css
.carousel-inner 
{ 
width:100%;
max-height:350px; 
}
.carousel-caption 
{
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 20%;
}

/*here is the css trick*/
.carousel-item {
  overflow:hidden;
}

img.crop-img {
/*adjust the percentage for based on image high*/
/*try out differernt number to see how it change the view*/
  margin-top: -20%;
  margin-bottom: -15%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!--Carousel Wrapper-->
<div id="carousel-home" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel">
    <!--Indicators-->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carousel-home" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-home" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-home" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <!--Slides-->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
            <div class="view">
                <img class="crop-img d-block w-100 mx-auto" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/0oBPS.jpg" alt="First slide">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h3>Light mask</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="crop-img d-block w-100 mx-auto" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/0oBPS.jpg" alt="Second slide">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h3>Strong mask</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="crop-img d-block w-100 mx-auto" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/0oBPS.jpg" alt="Third slide">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h3>Slight mask</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--Controls-->
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carousel-home" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carousel-home" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For `object-fit: cover` to work you need to have `width: 100%` and `height: 100%` on image.

Also put `overflow: hidden` on parent of image and it should work. `object-fit` properties won't work if image does not have `width` and `height` set to it.

It won't work if you only set `max-width` and `max-height` to image so keep that in mind